# Can't change color of border while focusing on input tag

Tags: html, css, frontend

i am trying to change the border color of my input while focus but it's not change.

```css
.input_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.input_bar {
    width:90%;
    height: 80%;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 15px;
    /* top right bottom left*/
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid 1px rgb(206,212,218);
}

.input_bar:focus {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
    <div class="input_container">
        <input class="input_bar" type="text" placeholder="title" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Use `:focus-visible`, not `:focus` (well, actually, you need to define both, due to how the CSS/HTML spec was revised a couple of years ago)

Comment: still not working while using :focus-visible .

Comment: check this video out [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dhgxNWuoJEjCQS5IbuOGTStvi-zojENL/view?usp=sharing). still not working.

Comment: @EverLoser check  my answer this will work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `outline: none` in `input_bar` class

Check below-working answer

```css
.input_container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    
}

.input_bar{
    width:90%;
    height: 80%;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 15px;
            /* top right bottom left*/
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    border: solid 1px rgb(206,212,218);
}

.input_bar:focus{
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="input_container">
    <input class="input_bar" type="text" placeholder="title" />
</div>
```